# Booting from a USB: Black screen and flashing cursor

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, usb

I've been trying to install Ubuntu (20.04) on a PC. But have been unable to get to the installation screen. After selecting the USB in the boot menu, the screen goes black with a flashing underscore/cursor.

My current process has been:

1. Install the .iso from the website
2. Flash a USB using BalenaEtcher (on Windows 10)
3. Turn off PC
4. turn on PC and enter the bios screen (Asus variant)
5. 'Boot' from the USB

If I was able to get through to the installation screen I was looking to install Ubuntu onto a Samsung M.2 SSD

I've tried:

- Changing the USB port
- Using a different USB (32GB)
- Another version of Ubuntu (as well as trying Linux Mint and Manjaro/KDE which have had exactly the same issue)

Additional debugging that I've tried:

- Ctrl+Alt+F1 and Ctrl+Alt+F3 also don't bring up a virtual console

I'm wondering now if it's the hardware that's unsupported?

- Processor: Intel i5-4690K CPU @ 3.50GHz, 3501 Mhz
- Motherboard: Z97-A-USB31 (Asus)
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti

Any additional pointers or advice would be really helpful, thanks!

Comment: Hello. How much memory does the machine have? Does the SSD drive need a firmware update? Did you verify the ISO before making the Live Media? Did you try and make the Live Media with Rufus? Most people have best results with it.

Comment: @David I tried each of your suggestions in the order you recommended. Using Rufus to create the .iso was what fixed it.
I'm a bit surprised that BalenaEtcher didn't work, as it's what's recommended on the [Ubuntu setup](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#3-create-a-bootable-usb-stick) page.
Eitherway, big thank you for helping out! (Not sure if I can mark this as answered now?)

Comment: There are quite a few question here on this site that say that BalenaEtcher did not work. Glad it worked for you. I will make it an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the install fails to work there are several things you can check out.

1. Does the machine meet the minimum specs for the version of Ubuntu you are trying to install.
2. Does the SSD drive need a firmware update. Even a new drive may need this.
3. Did you verify the ISO before making the Live Media? Here is the link with step by step instructions on how to verify an ISO file. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview
4. Use a different tool to make the Live Media. Many have had the best results when using the Rufus Application to make the Live media. Here is a link to download and get more info on Rufus.https://rufus.ie/en/
5. Do not give up if it fails the first time. This is not all the possible reasons an install will fail but covers a large number of the most common ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom (trying to boot LTS 20.04, got black screen with blinking cursor). Tried Rufus versions and everything, no luck. I solved it by downloading a 32-bit image to run on my 32-bit Pentium M laptop from 2005. So it's also worth checking that you have the right architecture selected.